# How to call a db method interface on page destory, in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

On page destroy method 'Dispose()' I am calling a method of an interface which updates the database. But it gived me an error that I can't call methods on a disposed DbContext.

Is there any way to call a method when the page is closed?

Comment: The lifetime of the dbcontext on server side Blazor is managed by the DI system if you are not creating the context your self. I would suggest to try using the ```NavigationManager```. It has event when navigation is happening. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers

Comment: This doesn't look like a good idea. Once your component is being disposed you cannot be certain that any of the objects it references haven't already been disposed too - What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In Razor Page
@implements IDisposable

an then you can
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{